# secure spring boot with keycloak doenst return 403

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I am trying to implement my first spring boot application, secured with keycloak. I am total newbe on both of these, but I think I managed ok so far.  I have been looking at various tutorials, but the latest I worked with was [this](https://wstutorial.com/am/spring-boot-with-keycloak.html)
So, I have set up a spring boot/hibernate application that is working (as a proof of concept at the moment). So, now I want to secure it using keycloak. What I have is
Controller.java

```
@Controller // This means that this class is a Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/test") // This means URL's start with /demo (after Application path)
public class MainController {
 

    @Autowired
    GemhMainRepository repository;
    
    @Autowired
    CompaniesRepository gsisCompanies;
    
     @RequestMapping("/protected")
        public String protectedHello() {
           System.out.println("test"); return "Hello World, i was protected";
        }}
```

Main.java

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })//do not create security credentials. we will use our own
public class Main {

     @Bean
        public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakSpringBootConfigResolver(){
            return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
        }
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GsisApi.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
    server.port=8080
        
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
        
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://sqlHost:3306/Db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false
    spring.datasource.username=user
    spring.datasource.password=password
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name =com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true  
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration
    keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:31063/auth
    keycloak.realm=testRealm
    keycloak.resource=test_client
    keycloak.public-client=true
    keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=user
    keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/test
    keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider  = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                ;
    }
    
}
```

This seems to be working fine when I get a token from keycloak,

```
curl --data "grant_type=password&client_id=test_client&username=user&password=password&client_secret=xxx" 'http://localhost:31063/auth/realms/testRealm/protocol/openid-connect/token'
```

I do get a result when running

```
 curl localhost:8080/test/protected -H "Authorization: bearer xxxxxxx " --insecure
```

But when I try to use it with out the token I am not getting anything. Not even the message I am printing on the screen. I guess I need to get a 403 error, in order to inform the user that they must use some token.right? any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It seems that I got it to work. For some reason that I cant understand, following these instructions seems to do the trick. I created
**MyAuthenticationEntryPoint.java**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
  @Override
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    // 401
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Authentication Failed");
  }

  @ExceptionHandler (value = {AccessDeniedException.class})
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException {
    // 403
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Authorization Failed : " + accessDeniedException.getMessage());
  }

  @ExceptionHandler (value = {Exception.class})
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      Exception exception) throws IOException {
     // 500
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Internal Server Error : " + exception.getMessage());
  }

}
```

and added this to my **SecurityConfig.java**

```
http.exceptionHandling()
      .authenticationEntryPoint(new MyAuthenticationEntryPoint());
```

making it

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider  = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/test/health/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                ;
      http.exceptionHandling()
      .authenticationEntryPoint(new MyAuthenticationEntryPoint());
    }
}
```

also by adding the  `.antMatchers("/test/health/*").permitAll()` I can call health with out any credentials.
I am not 100% confident of what I am doing. So if you see something not right, please let me know.